# Accessing an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, bank

I have Bank account program in which I am trying to delete an account

```
var bankAccount = new Array();
var bankAccountAll = new Array();

function DeleteAccount()
{
   var userno = document.getElementById("userno").value;
   bankAccount = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user');
   for(var i=0;i<bankAccount.length;i++)
   {
      bankAccountAll=bankAccount[i];
      if(userno==bankAccountAll[0])
     {
         bankAccount.splice(i,1);
      }
   }
  sessionStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(bankAccount));
}
```

I am getting the error at line

```
if (userno == bankAccountAll[0])
```

as "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Check whether your backAccountAll has any values in it or not.

Comment: It has @YashMaheshwari

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score -1):

**bankAccountAll** is an array so **bankAccountAll=bankAccount[i]** is a wrong statement.You can use **bankAccountAll.push(bankAccount[i])** to add element